# Do I need a menu resource for each layout resource

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app with an action bar and menu resource folder with an menu_main.xml file in it, I suppose I'm right in assuming that each resource file should have an activity?

If not is there a way to dynamically change the android:visible="false" to android:visible="true"? Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: If you have the same menu throughout your whole app then you can create e base Activity/Fragment with your menu and extend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menus are for Activities, not layouts.

To answer your question, there is a way to dynamically change the visibility. In your `onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)` method, you can set individual menu components to be visible/invisible.

Eg.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  menu.findItem(R.id.myMenuItem1).setVisible(false);
}
```

However, I would stick with making a separate menu xml per Activity - it's small (it is just text after all), and it helps make sure that you're not mixing stuff up.